# MySQL delete older then * hours

Tags: php, mysql

I want to use the following code to SELECT data older then 1 minute.

```
SELECT * FROM `auth_temp` WHERE date > (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MINUTE)
```

But it didn't work. Then I checked some other topics and one person talked about the server time, I just asked my host and he said the server time is: 15:30
When at my place and the logs in MySQL it is 21:30, aka 6 hours later.
Anyone how I should asjust my code to that?

Thank you all!

Comment: you have a column named date?

Comment: "older than x" suggest that you want rows with date values *less than* the specified date, not greater than.

Comment: @scaisEdge With php it gets inserted as: date('Y/m/d H:i:s'); And this is how the row looks: https://gyazo.com/a5377aaf03d12342cd67d6f376847fc9

Answer (score 1):

You are hitting a timezone issue. Most servers run on UTC. If you have a `TIMESTAMP` as the field type, MySQL will convert the time from server time to UTC and back. You can adjust what MySQL considers server time using `SET time_zone = timezone;` ([Docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_time_zone)). If you actually care about timezones it is advisable to just use UTC and convert in your application.

Comment: With php it gets inserted as: date('Y/m/d H:i:s'); And this is how the row looks: https://gyazo.com/a5377aaf03d12342cd67d6f376847fc9

Answer (score 0):

Your current SQL statement will only select data newer than 1 minute. Change it to:

`SELECT * FROM auth_temp WHERE date < (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MINUTE)`

This will select data that is older than one minute. If you are using `NOW()` for setting the date column when you are inserting the row then that small fix should do it even if the time zones are different between your application and database layer. If you are setting the date column from your application layer you will have syncing issues if the time zone is set differently than the database layer.

It sounds like the MySQL server is either running in a different time zone or running on Universal Time (UTC) which is common. Running MySQL on UTC time is a good way to deal with users in multiple time zones. In your code, you should be able to synchronize the time zones in use on the database and application layers if it's set to UTC time easily. If it's set to a different time zone, it should be possible as well but not recommended.

Comment: With php it gets inserted as: date('Y/m/d H:i:s'); And this is how the row looks: https://gyazo.com/a5377aaf03d12342cd67d6f376847fc9 Your line seems not to work, I just inserted a new row and its older then 5 minutes but its not showing it

Comment: If you're using PHP to format the date, MySQL needs it to be formatted like this: YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.  The PHP code would be: date('Y-m-d H:i:s');  Make sure this syncs with the Now() time being generated on the MySQL server, otherwise you will have to use the PHP time as well in the WHERE condition.